# Faster version of split{base} for very large data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with roughly three million rows (each row is a booking) and a small number of columns one of them beeing customer id. My goal is to split this data frame by customer id into a list of data frames such that each data frame contains all the bookings of a customer. So I tried

```
cstmr_list <- split(df, f = df$cstmr_id)
```

but cancelled it after half an hour because it took too long. Next, I only split the indexes with

```
idx_list <- split(seq(nrow(df)), f = df$cstmr_id)
```

which took less than 10s. Now, I want to populate `idx_list` with the corresponding rows of `df`. Who knows how to do it?

Comment: `cstmr_list <- lapply(idx_list, function(x) df[x,])` should do it. Not sure about the computation speed though.

Comment: It would be fastest to avoid explicit splitting. What is your next step? Why do you want to split? You can probably achieve your actual goal more efficiently by changing your whole approach.

Comment: Agree with Roland, most likely you could solve your problems by `dplyr::group_by(cstmr_id)`, and then doing your customer-level analysis, or something similar from `data.table` package.

Comment: @all As proposed, I will do my customer-level analysis with dplyr as Leo's idea seems to be very slow, too (I cancelled it after half an hour).